How to designate abbreviations that are neither acronyms nor initialisms?
Acronyms and initialisms are special kinds of abbreviations.

(image source)
How to designate abbreviations that are neither acronyms nor initialisms?

Examples:

Dr.: doctor
lb.: pound (from the Latin "libra")
No.: number (from the Latin "numero")
vs.: versus


Give us an example. There are also clippings and back formations

Very common in the UK is 'He is a see you next Tuesday'.

@Mari-LouA added, but ideally looking for a generic answer.

Just "abbreviations", AFAIK. BTW, there's LoCA, a real mix, for longitudinal chromatic aberration. Not exactly an acronym... but not an abbreviation.

'Shortened form' doesn't have to mean 'with the end of the word left off'. Dr and vs (first and last letters) are still 'shortened'.

@KateBunting yes those are abbreviations. Just wondering whether there exist a more precise term to to designate abbreviations that are neither acronyms nor initialisms.

As others have said - no.

I think you answered it yourself: "abbreviation." Note that, although we have a grid with three equal columns, the definitions for "initialism" and "acronym" both start with "An abbreviation..." That is, "abbreviation" is the overarching category, and it contains the special categories "acronym" and "initialism."
